# ng-if doesn't work properly on a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show a specific div only while a function return true value... why isn't it working here ?

```
var app = angular.module('. . .');

app.controller('LoaderController', function($scope, $http,communication) {

  var loader = this;
  var isLoading = false;

  $scope.Loading = false;

  this.getIsLoading = function(){
    return true; // return communication.getIsLoading();
  }


});
```

This is the div

```
<div id="loader" ng-controller="LoaderController as loaderCtrl" ng-if="loaderCtrl.getIsLoading()"></div>
```

Comment: Don't mix and match the `$scope` syntax with the `Controller-As` syntax.

Comment: You can use 'ng-show' instead of 'ng-if'. Because until element is loaded in DOM controller can't invoke. Also you mixed-up the isolated scope and 'as' syntax so be careful and follow only one way.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use ng-if in the same html directive that invokes the controller. Think about it -- the controller needs to exist for angular to call that method on it.

Move ng-if down a level or the move the ng-controller up one and it should work.

Comment: glad to help :)